# Issue in rendering collection of forms in Symfony 2.0

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the following User entity:

```
class User extends BaseUser implements ParticipantInterface
{   
     /**
     * @Exclude()   
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\MainBundle\Entity\PreferredContactType", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $preferredContactTypes;

   /**
     * Add preferredContactType
     *
     * @param \App\MainBundle\Entity\PreferredContactType $preferredContactType
     * @return User
     */
    public function addPreferredContactTypes(\App\MainBundle\Entity\PreferredContactType $preferredContactType)
    {
        $this->preferredContactTypes[] = $preferredContactType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove preferredContactType
     *
     * @param \App\MainBundle\Entity\PreferredContactType $preferredContactType
     */
    public function removePreferredContactTypes(\App\MainBundle\Entity\PreferredContactType $preferredContactType)
    {
        $this->preferredContactTypes->removeElement($preferredContactType);
    }

    /**
     * Get preferredContactType
     *
     * @return \App\MainBundle\Entity\PreferredContactType 
     */
    public function getPreferredContactTypes()
    {
        return $this->preferredContactTypes;
    }
}
```

I wanted to create a form that displays multiple choices of the preferredContactType:

```
  $contactOptions = $em->getRepository('AppMainBundle:ContactType')->findAll();
  $settingsForm = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array(
            'contact' => $contactOptions,
        ));
```

and here's what my UserType looks like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
                $builder->add('preferredContactTypes', 'collection', array('type' => 'choice', 'options' => array('choices'  => $options['contact'], 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true)))

                ;

    }
```

but now I am getting an error of:

Expected an array.

[image]

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because you pass to `choices` parameter instance of ArrayCollection class (that was returned in `$em->getRepository('AppMainBundle:ContactType')->findAll();`). But `choices` parameter need to be array (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices).

You can use `toArray()` method on your ArrayCollection to retrieve the array but it will not give the expected result because it will be array of instances of `ContactType`.

The best way to form some choice list from entity is to use `entity` type instead of `choice`. See more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html.

Also you can implement `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface` in some class and use it as parameter `choice_list` in `choice` form field. For example you can extend `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList` and implement `loadChoiceList()` method.